# How to set the "Default Project" property in Visual Studio

Tags: c#, visual-studio

I know that there are several questions asking seemingly similar things:
[Question 1,](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4797481/visual-studio-set-default-project-on-project-or-solution-settings) [Question 2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/694730/why-is-set-as-startup-option-stored-in-the-suo-file-and-not-the-sln-file)

These all answer how to set the default startup project, but they don't answer how to change the "Default Project" property. I have been following [this](https://www.pluralsight.com/guides/microsoft-net/configuring-asp-net-identity) tutorial on *Configuring ASP.Net Identity*. About 2/3 of the way down the page it has a number list with #1 being:

> 1. Set the `Default Project` property to `WebApi`.
> 2. Open the `Package Manager Console`.
> 3. Enable migrations by targeting our custom context: Enable-Migrations -`contexttypename AppUsersDbContext`
> 4. Add a migration: `Add-Migration Initial`
> 5. `Update-Database`

The other answers talk about changing the order of projects to set one of them as the *default startup project*, but this makes it sound as if there is some property named default project that I need to change.

Just some background - the tutorial starts by creating the solution. Only one project is added, so it wouldn't make sense to set a default startup project.

The tutorial doesn't have a date, but speaks of using SQL Server 2016, so it is fairly recent.

Thanks for any help you can offer, the project was working fine until this point, but after doing the rest of the list, something broke. I don't know if this is to blame, but I think it is possible I misunderstood what he meant by this and did something incorrectly.

Once again, thanks so much for any help,

Taylor

Answer (score 6, accepted):

That [tutorial](https://www.pluralsight.com/guides/microsoft-net/configuring-asp-net-identity) is talking about Nuget, not your project/solution.

To change the default project in Nuget, you should see a drop down on your "**Package Manager Console**" tab in visual studio.

As @ScottChamberlain pointed out, the tutorial is a bit flawed with their ordering.  Had Step 2 (Open Package Manager Console) been performed before Step 1, you would likely be able to find the "Default Project" drop down.

Anyways, open **Package Manager Console** and you should look something like this: [image]

Comment: Step 1 and Step 2  of that section should really be reversed in that tutorial.

Comment: I agree, it would have most likely saved OP from having to post this question.

Comment: [I sent a request](https://github.com/pluralsight/guides/pull/216) to have it fixed

Comment: Please, next time provide the most necessary steps in the answer, because not I get 404 and the answer is useless.

Comment: @LueTm the instructions and a screenshot are already included in my answer. There is literally nothing more you need. The linked tutorial was the same tutorial that OP was using that had the flawed instructions that OP has _already_ included in their question.